# Is it possible to convert a two light circuit into a four light circuit (one switch)?

Tags: electrical

I have two long multi-light fixtures controlled by one switch in my bathroom.  Is it safe/possible to replace/wire for four or five two light bulb fixtures? Is there a limit of wattage or any other consideration?  There are no other lights or switches on the circuit.

Comment: If your new fixtures are LED and the original fixture were not, then just do it.  It would be almost impossible to exceed the old load with modern LED regardless of how many.

Answer (score 2):

The circuit you are talking about is probably rated at 15-Amps.  The electric math looks like this:  15 (amps) x 120 (volts) = 1800-watts.  It is always a good idea to derate your circuit at by 80%.  (This gives you a margin of safety.)  1800 x 80% = 1440-watts. All things being equal you can install this kind of wattage on this circuit.  It doesn't really matter how you do it.

Comment: Don’t forget to add in other lights and outlets when using these calculations.  You’ll need to identify what turns off when the breaker for that circuit is shut off.